# Bootstrap how to align side by side a button and a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to align side by side a link and a button. I know that I can use `btn-link` but in my case I have to use the `a` element for the link. I create a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zpa9nf7wNP) to show the issue.

The anchor link is slighly (1px) above the text of the `btn-link` button.

Comment: You can apply `.btn-link` to `<a>`s too

Comment: same issue even if I apply `btn-link`.

Comment: you need both `.btn` and `.btn-link` to work, or if you prefer you can also set `a{vertical-align:middle;} in your CSS`

Comment: Both are working. I will use the `vertical-align` in my case. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use button classes on links too, so you could have:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Text</button>
<button class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#">An anchor link</a>
```

Of course this will add some extra padding to the link.

Another option is to adjust the vertical alignment of the link via CSS:

```
a{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See the **[updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ulKQc5LwLj)**